# XDocument load with environment variables

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

When I try to load some XML file, with next code:

```
XDocument configuration = 
    XDocument.Load("%NAME_OF_THE_PATH%/Default_TestRunConfiguration.xml");
```

It doesn't seams to work, it cannot parse the specific environment variable that I have specified. When I paste that variable into explorer, it works. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%NAME_OF_THE_PATH%/Default_TestRunConfiguration.xml");

XDocument configuration = XDocument.Load(path);
```

This will work with multiple environment variables, and avoids you having to handle them specially.
It means you can use the same sort of string as you would in a batch file.

Comment: This particular example better suits my needs. Since I have a variable that contains environment variable together with some folders after it, and this example translates it :) thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Use [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to safely combine the path and file name.

```
var dir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("someVariableWithYourPath");

XDocument configuration =
    XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(dir, "Default_TestRunConfiguration.xml"));
```

Currently, you pass the literal string "%NAME_OF_THE_PATH%/Default_TestRunConfiguration.xml" to the method, and it doesn't know the first part represents an environment variable.